# Splunk conditional count

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have some CSV data about files imported in to Splunk. The data looks like this:

```
"\\domain\path\to\file\","<filename>","<fsize>","<ext>","<Last_access>","<last_write>","<creation_time>","<attributes>","<owner>"
```

I have converted all the date strings to epoch using:

```
| eval epoch_LastAccessTime=strptime(LastAccessTime, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
...
...
```

I want to get:

- A percentage of files last accessed between 6 months and 3 years ago
- A percentage of files last accessed 3 years or more ago.

This is the search query that I have tried before getting stuck:

```
index="<my_index>" sourcetype="<my_sourcetype>" 
| rex field=DirectoryName "\\\domain\.org\\\teams\\\(?<Team>[^\\\]*)" 
offset_field=_extracted_fields_bounds  
| eval epoch_LastAccessTime=strptime(LastAccessTime, "%d/%m/%Y 
%H:%M:%S") 
| eval _time=epoch_LastAccessTime
| timechart span=6mon count
```

I've tried using commands along the lines of:

```
| where epoch_LastAccessTime>=three_year_ago_from_now AND 
epoch_LastAccessTime<=six_months_ago_from_now
```

However, this excludes everything else (3y+)

I want the result to look something like:

```
TimeRange  Perc
6m-3y      60%
3y+        40%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit: [Lowell](https://answers.splunk.com/users/170/Lowell.html?utm_source=answers&utm_medium=email&utm_term=Lowell%E2%99%A6&utm_content=&utm_campaign=mention)

Instead of using a `where` to limit your results, use an `eval` to build a new categorical field.

At that point you'll no longer need the timechart.

Something like:

```
| eval TimeRange=case(epoch_LastAccessTime>=three_year_ago_from_now, "3y+",
                      epoch_LastAccessTime>=six_months_ago_from_now, "6m-3y",
                      0=0, "less than 6m")
| stats count by TimeRange
| eventstats sum(count) as total_count
| eval pct=100*count/total_count
```